# Fitting a big (and variable) number of datasets with shared and individual parameters in Python

Tags: python, curve-fitting, shared, symfit

I have N (approx. 1000) datasets that I want to fit with the same polynomial model, where the second and higher order should be shared parameters and the first order will be individual to each set. The number of datasets will not always be same, but might vary.

To do so, I have a matrix with shape `N` x `length` and an x vector with shape `length`, which is valid for all datasets.

By searching for a solution, I came across symfit, but apparently it seems like, it is impossible to give all datasets in a matrix to symfit. Instead symfit asks to give every vector seperately, which seems difficult to me.

Have you ever done something similar? Or an idea how to solve it?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the section about how to [ask] and illustrate your question with your own coding efforts. Be specific and clear because the people reading your post do not know the context of your problem.

Comment: ...just use `least_sqares` and write your own residual function.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your problem correctly because symfit is agnostic about the shapes of your data. As long as the shapes you provide make sense, i.e. there is no ambiguity about how they have to be contracted, then it should work. Perhaps you could provide a Minimal Working Example of what you want exactly? (Or cite the example from the symfit docs and why it wouldn't work in your case)

Comment: Hi all, thank you for your help. I continued to work on it, came a bit further and reformulated my question (including minimal working example). You can find it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63058045/problems-with-least-squares-method-from-scipy-when-fitting-polynomials-with-shar